# iqueryable select/where not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, nhibernate

I have two tables Boxer and Prospect. Boxers has general stuff like name and and dob etc and a BoxerId
While Prospect contains only one value (at the moment) which is a boxerId. 
If a boxer is a prospect(up and coming boxer) there Id will be in the prospect table.

This works fine but now I want to select all boxers that are prospects

```
    public static IQueryable<Boxer> IsProspect(this IQueryable<Boxer> query)
    {
        //this does not filter down to only prospects!!!
        return query.Where(x => x.Prospect != null);
    }
```

This is the function I call using:

```
var repository = GetRepository<Boxer>();
var boxers = repository.Query().IsProspect();
```

I would hope this would filter my collection of all boxers down to just boxers that are prospects!

Oddly it doesnt filter it but if i hover over my boxers object and look at each boxer during debugging I can see "IsProspect" true or false correctly
[IsProspect Debug Example http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/4361/isprospect.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/4361/isprospect.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should use [table-per-subclass inheritance](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass).

Comment: i dont really know what im looking at here any help?

Comment: From your problem description, it sounds like (conceptually) you have a `Boxer` domain object, and a `Prospect` derived domain object. That is, the `Prospect` class is derived from `Boxer`. I re-read your question and realized you use NHibernate and not LINQ to Entities, so I changed the link to point to the relevant NH docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only those objects where IsProspect is true then use that as your predicate:

```
public static IQueryable<Boxer> IsProspect(this IQueryable<Boxer> query)
{
    return query.Where(x => x.IsProspect);
}
```

Comment: That fails to work with the error/no values returned!
{"could not resolve property: IsProspect of: BensBoxing.Domain.Boxer"}

Answer (score 0):

overload a `datacontext` and directly call the function from your `datacontext` object

```
public partial class myDataContext
{
       public IQueryable<Boxer> IsProspect()
       {
             return from tBoxer in myDataContext.tBoxer 
                    where tBoxer.IsProspect == true             
                    select tBoxer;
       }
}
```

and you would call it like a normal function call like so `var db = new myDataConext();` `var prospects = db.IsProspect();`